# How to solve my Fibonaci recursive method in Ruby

Tags: ruby

```
def fibs_rec(n)

  return 1 if n == 1 || n == 0

  puts fibs_rec(n-1) + fibs_rec(n-2) 

end 

fibs_rec(5)
```

It's giving me the error

```
"undefined method '+' for nil:Nilclass"
```

I dont know what that means. How is it being turned to nil.

Comment: `puts` returns `nil` so `fibs_rec` returns `nil` for any argument other than `0` and `1`.

Comment: Ruby v2.7 has given us [Enumerator::produce](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-c-produce), which allows us to write `Enumerator.produce([0, 1]) { |fib0, fib1| [fib1, fib0 + fib1] }.take(15).map(&:first) #=> [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377] )`.

Comment: If you want to display the return value of a method it's always better to do that outside the method. That way you don't need to change the method if you want to use it elsewhere or later to just return the value. That is, remove `puts` from your method and write `fib = fibs_rec(n); puts fib`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes that works but its not giving what i want. I want it to display all the fibonacci numbers all the way from the beginning to the limit provided by the argument. The way you told it just outputs the fibnocci number at the position specified by the argument and thats the reason i replaced return with puts

Comment: Couldn't one write `n = 10; puts Enumerator.produce([0, 1]) { |fib0, fib1| [fib1, fib0 + fib1] }.take(n).map(&:first).join(' ') #=> "0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34"`? In any event, my comment was meant merely as a public service announcement about the existence of `Enumerator::produce`, which readers may find useful in some situations. The second is general advice, having nothing to do with Fibs.

Answer (score 0):

When you do recursion, the recursive function (or `method` in Ruby's term) must return a value. Ruby's `puts` method, on the other hand, [returns `nil`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-puts).

You must move the `puts` method out of the recursion so that the `fibs_rec` method always returns a value.

Answer (score 0):

Make the method actually return the generated number:

```
def fibs_rec(n)
  return 1 if n == 1 || n == 0
  (fibs_rec(n-1) + fibs_rec(n-2)).tap do |result|
    puts result
  end
end
```

`.tap` lets you yield an object to a block and always return the object itself.

Comment: `.tap` yields `(fibs_rec(n-1) + fibs_rec(n-2))` to the block and returns it as well.